# puppet: Not authorized to call find

Tags: puppet, selinux

I'm running puppet 2.7.26 because that's what the redhat package provides.

I'm trying to serve files that are **NOT** stored within any puppet modules.  The files are maintained in another location on the puppet server, and that is where I need to serve them from.

I have this in my /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf

```
[files]
  path /var/www/cobbler/pub
  allow *
```

And then I have a class file like this:

```
class etchostfile
(
  $hostfile              /* declare that this class has one parameter */
)

{
  File
  {
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0644',
  }

  file { $hostfile :
    ensure => file,
    source => "puppet:///files/hosts-${hostfile}.txt",
    path => '/root/hosts',
  }
}
```

But when my node calls

```
class { 'etchostfile' :
   hostfile => foo,
}
```

I get this error

> err: /Stage[main]/Etchostfile/File[foo]: Could not evaluate: Error 400
>   on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on
>   /file_metadata/files/hosts-foo.txt with {:links=>"manage"} Could not
>   retrieve file metadata for puppet:///files/hosts-foo.txt: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Not authorized to call find on
>   /file_metadata/files/hosts-foo.txt with {:links=>"manage"} at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/etchostfile/manifests/init.pp:27

This post
https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/puppet-error-400-on-server-not-authorized-to-call-find/
indicates that this is all I need to do.  But I must be missing something.

---

UPDATE

When I run the master in debug mode, I get no error.

The master responds thusly:

```
info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing * access
info: access[^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' save
info: access[^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
info: access[/file]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate/ca]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate/]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate/]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate/]: allowing * access
info: access[/certificate_request]: adding authentication any
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' find
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing 'method' save
info: access[/certificate_request]: allowing * access
info: access[/]: adding authentication any
info: Inserting default '/status' (auth true) ACL because none were found in '/etc/puppet/auth.conf'
info: Expiring the node cache of agent.redacted.com
info: Not using expired node for agent.redacted.com from cache; expired at Thu Aug 13 14:18:48 +0000 2015
info: Caching node for agent.redacted.com 
debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/etchostfile/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported etchostfile from etchostfile into production
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for selrange
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for group
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for seluser
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for selrole
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for owner
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for mode
debug: File[foo]: Adding default for seltype
notice: Compiled catalog for agent.redacted.com in environment production in 0.11 seconds
info: mount[files]: allowing * access
debug: Received report to process from agent.redacted.com 
debug: Processing report from agent.redacted.com with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
```

and the agent responds thusly:

```
info: Caching catalog for agent.redacted.com
info: Applying configuration version '1439475588'
notice: /Stage[main]/Etchostfile/File[foo]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}75125a96a68a0ff0d42f91f10dca8336'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.42 seconds
```

and the file is properly installed/updated.

So it works when the master is in debug mode, but it errors when the master is in standard (?) mode.  I can go back and forth, in and out of debug mode at will, and it works every time in debug mode, and it fails every time in standard mode.

---

UPDATE 2

Running `puppetmasterd` from the command line, and everything works.

Running `service puppetmaster start` or `/etc/init.d/puppetmaster start` from the command line, and it fails.  So at least I'm getting closer.

`/etc/sysconfig/puppetmaster` is entirely commented out.  So as of now, I do not see any difference between just starting puppetmasterd and using the service script.

---

UPDATE 3

I think it's an SELinux problem.

With SELinux "enforcing" on the master, `service puppetmaster restart`, and I get the error.

I change SELinux to "Permissive" on the master, and I still get the error.

But now that SELinux is set to Permissive, if I `service puppetmaster restart`, my files get served properly.

But now that it's working, I set SELinux to Enforcing, and I get a different error:

```
err: /Stage[main]/Etchostfile/File[foo]: Could not evaluate: Could not
retrieve information from environment production source(s)
puppet:///files/hosts-foo.txt at
/etc/puppet/modules/etchostfile/manifests/init.pp:27
```

Then I do a `service puppetmaster restart` and I'm back to the original error.

So the situation changes depending on

- how I started the service (`puppetmasterd` or `service`)
- what SELinux was set to when I started the service
- what SELinux is set to when the agent runs.

The closer I get, the more confused I get.

---

UPDATE 4

I think I found it.  Once I started looking at SELinux, I found the policy changes I needed to make (allowing ruby/puppet to access cobbler files) and now it appears to be working...

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html#serving-files-from-custom-mount-points) agrees. Debug this by stopping the master, then starting a standalone process using `puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose --debug`, then doing an agent run.

Comment: @FelixFrank : updated with debug output.  TLDR: it works in debug mode, but when I come out of debug mode, it fails with the same error.

Comment: Your Update 4 should be expanded to an answer I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an SELinux problem.  I eventually found this error message

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/ruby from read access
on the file /var/www/cobbler/pub/hosts-foo.txt .
```

which led me to the audit2allow rules I needed to apply to allow puppet to access my cobbler files.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error with puppet server on ubuntu 20.

Error: /Stage[main]/Dvod_tocr/File[/install/wine-data.tar.gz]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///extra_files/wine-data.tar.gz: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/extra_files/wine-data.tar.gz with {:rest=>"extra_files/wine-data.tar.gz", :links=>"manage", :checksum_type=>"sha256", :source_permissions=>"ignore"}

My fileserver.conf file was in the wrong location. The correct location for this puppet version and on ubuntu 20 is /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/fileserver.conf